# Loading more than one .json file in Python 2.7 by looping through a directory

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have three .json files in a directory, and I'm trying to loop through this directory to load all three .json files. However something interesting happens: the code does not produce an error, but it only loads one of the three .json files. I can see that it does this because I am assigning the json.load function to a variable, and then entering variable['someKey']['someInnerKey'] in the interpreter (the .json files have one level of nesting).

Below is the code I am using. I've spent some time searching through many posts here dealing with reading and opening .json files, but I haven't found the one "Aha!" post as of yet. I'll keep digging, but if anyone has any suggestions or tips, they would be much appreciated.

```
import json, os  
for filename in os.listdir('D:/path1/path2/'):
    if filename.endswith('.json'):
        with open(os.path.join('D:/path1/path2/',filename)) as json_file:
            variable = json.load(json_file)
```

Comment: you are assigning to `variable` on every iteration, therefore overwriting the previous computations

Comment: OK - That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import json, os  

variables = {}

for filename in os.listdir('D:/path1/path2/'):
    if filename.endswith('.json'):
        with open(os.path.join('D:/path1/path2/',filename)) as json_file:
            variables[filename] = json.load(json_file)
```

Then your `variables` dictionary will contain the loaded json with the filename as the key rather than just overwriting `variable`

Comment: Hey Drew G. - that works and makes sense. I can see the .json files with variables.keys(), and can access the sub and sub-sub keys within each one. Thanks!